# POST doesn't call the expected method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on ASP.Net Web API with two or more Post Methods. I am trying to consume one of the Post methods from api controller through HttpClient, but everytime the first Post Method is called. 
Below is the code

```
public class JobController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage RunJob([FromBody]UserModel User)
    {
    }

[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(string ExportStatusGuid, string PartnerGuid, string UserEmail, string Password)
    {
    }
}
```

And what I am trying to do to consume it through HTTP Client is:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var arguments = new { ExportStatusGuid, PartnerGuid };
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arguments), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var responseTask = client.PostAsync(ApiUrl + "Job/DownloadFile", content);
            responseTask.Wait();

            if (responseTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {


            }
        }
```

You can see I have called DownloadFile from JobController

```
var responseTask = client.PostAsync(ApiUrl + "Job/DownloadFile", content);
```

but instead of calling Job/DownloadFile, it run Job/RunJob method. I could not figure out the problem, even I have tried to add Route configurations.

The default route config is here

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HttpClient. Your controller exposes `RunJob` as the *default* post action, because it's the only method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute. `DownloadFile` is just a method

Comment: Change your PostAsync to GetAsync

Comment: @Shiljo the question is how to *POST*, not how to *GET*. In any case, there's no GET action in this controller

Comment: If you want to turn `DownloadFile` into an action, add the `HttpPost` attribute to it

Comment: Sorry, while copying code, I missed HttpPost, in application, HttpPost attribute is there on both methods. I have updated the question

Comment: got it @PanagiotisKanavos & it is always good to have the verb attributes included. that should solve the issue

Comment: No, it did not resolve the issue. @Shiljo

Comment: try including [Route("DownloadFile")] attirbute on method and on class [RoutePrefix("api")]

Answer (score 0):

change route config

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: @azharrahi you need to add action name in route